# ZFTool: Class 'Zend\Log\ProcessorPluginManager' not found error

Tags: php, zend-framework, zftool2

After install the [ZFTool](https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool) I was trying to test if it works, but I'm always receiving the following error:

```
fernando@pudim:~/tmp$ php zf.php version

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend\Log\ProcessorPluginManager' not found in /home/fernando/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/Zend/Mvc/Service/AbstractPluginManagerFactory.php on line 32
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/fernando/tmp/zf.php:0
PHP   2. Zend\Mvc\Application::init() /home/fernando/tmp/zf.php:50
PHP   3. Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModules() /home/fernando/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:252
PHP   4. Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger() /home/fernando/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:123
PHP   5. Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners() /home/fernando/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
PHP   6. call_user_func() /home/fernando/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
PHP   7. Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ServiceListener->onLoadModulesPost() /home/fernando/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:468
PHP   8. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get() /home/fernando/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ServiceListener.php:212
PHP   9. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create() /home/fernando/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:525
PHP  10. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate() /home/fernando/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:593
PHP  11. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory() /home/fernando/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:633
PHP  12. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback() /home/fernando/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:1055
PHP  13. call_user_func() /home/fernando/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:923
PHP  14. Zend\Mvc\Service\AbstractPluginManagerFactory->createService() /home/fernando/tmp/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:923
```

**Note:** I have ZFTool installed into `/home/fernando/tmp/` folder.

#### What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this Github issue](https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool/issues/92), I've found the answer.

**Just add the following into your `composer.json` file:**

```
"zendframework/zend-log": ">=2.3.0"
```

**After that, your `composer.json` file will probably appear something like that:**

```
{
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zftool": "dev-master",
        "zendframework/zend-log": ">=2.3.0"
    }
}
```

**Now you just need to update / install the new packages**. Run the following command in your Terminal: `composer update` or `php composer.phar update`.

**Testing:**

```
fernando@pudim:~/tmp$ php zf.php version
ZFTool - Zend Framework 2 command line Tool
The application in this folder is using Zend Framework 2.3.4
```

Hope it help, guys!